Date of last PR as of the date in current row
I want to return the complete date for each row where the LINE='PR'.
No cross join please, the table has millions of records.
alter session set DATE_INPUT_FORMAT='DD-MM-YYYY';
create database testdb; use database testdb;
create table test_table(
   location int
 , line text
 , start_ date
 , complete date );

insert into test_table values
 (10003281, 'P', '30-08-2024','30-08-2024')
,(10003281, 'P', '22-03-2024','22-03-2024')
,(10003281, 'PR', null,       '13-02-2024')
,(10003281, 'P', '13-02-2024','13-02-2024')
,(10003281, 'P', '18-12-2023','11-01-2024')
,(10003281, 'P', '21-11-2023','21-11-2023')
,(10003281, 'P', '07-08-2023','11-10-2023')
,(10003281, 'PR', null,       '07-08-2023');

Expected result should be



LOCATION
LINE
START
COMPLETE
PRDATE




10003281
P
30-08-2024
30-08-2024
13-02-2024


10003281
P
22-03-2024
22-03-2024
13-02-2024


10003281
PR

13-02-2024
13-02-2024


10003281
P
13-02-2024
13-02-2024
07-08-2023


10003281
P
18-12-2023
11-01-2024
07-08-2023


10003281
P
21-11-2023
21-11-2023
07-08-2023


10003281
P
07-08-2023
11-10-2023
07-08-2023


10003281
PR

07-08-2023
07-08-2023




You can use an asof join.

Snowflake doesn't use T-SQL so why have you tagged both?

I am going to assume your tables are in csv format, since you did not provide info about the format of the tables. I'll use the csv Python library. You may also use Pandas library if you have it installed, but this is a simple method.
import csv

# Open the CSV file
with open('yourfile.csv', mode='r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    
    # Loop through each row in the CSV
    for row in reader:
        # Check if the Line column contains 'PR'
        if row['Line'] == 'PR':
            print("start: " + str(row['Start']) + ", end: " + str(row['Complete']))
        # break

This will loop through your csv file and check the line column if it is 'PR'. When it is 'PR' it prints the start and complete date on that line. If you want to stop on first 'PR', just call break after. I hope that helps.


Scan once, maintaining a window partitioned by location and ordered by complete, with a frame between unbounded preceding and current row.
This lets you see the last_value(complete) in that window, which is your prdate. Since you only consider those with line='PR', you can nullify the rest with an iff() and tell the window to ignore nulls.

select location
     , line
     , start_
     , complete
     , last_value(iff(line='PR',complete,null))ignore nulls
     --max(iff(line='PR',complete,null))--another method
         over(partition by location 
              order by complete, line
              rows between unbounded preceding
                       and current row) as prdate
from test_table
order by complete desc
       , line desc;

You could also try an ASOF JOIN:
select location
     , t1.line
     , t1.start_
     , t1.complete
     , iff(t1.line='PR',t1.complete,t2.complete) as prdate
from test_table as t1 
asof join (select location,complete
           from test_table where line='PR') as t2 
match_condition(t1.complete > t2.complete)
using(location)
order by t1.complete desc;

The iff() resolves the 2024-02-13 case where you seem to want the P to stick with an earlier PR instead of the one on the same date, but the PR itself has to keep its date instead of falling back on the preceding one.
The window function does that by adding line as the secondary order by column that puts PR after P if they share a date, so that P doesn't see that PR when looking back.
